# How do I do get-itemproperty with an added SPECIFIC-WORD filter?

Tags: powershell, filter, wmic

I found that WMIC doesn't get all installed software because it takes information from some specific/default registry as unique, and that registry alone doesn't contain the full list of software shown on Control Panel.

I found that this Powershell command line DO FIND the software installed listed-and-not-listed by wmic:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate
```

BUT, I need to add a **FILTER** to that line (and I'm sorry I don't know Powershell that deep) to filter for specific name, i.e. 'Teamv', so it shows me ONLY software that **start/contain that word**, so I can find out if the software is installed or not.

IF (IF) also there exist a way to get from a list of words (let say you want to find out more that one software installed,i.e. Teamviewer, Kaspersky and Logmein) that would be awesome!!

Thanks for any help ! =)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell offers the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet
for filtering a list of *objects* - wether as a whole or by property values:

```bash
Get-ItemProperty `
    HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*,
    HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  Where-Object DisplayName -match 'Teamviewer|Kaspersky|LogMeIn|net' |
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate, PSPath
```

Note:

- A 64-bit version of Windows is assumed, where you need to check *two* registry keys: one for 64-bit, and another for 32-bit applications (`Wow6432Node`).

  - If you want to see which of the two keys the results came from, you can add `PSPath` to the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call (the values of that property have a PowerShell-specific provider prefix; to get the registry-native key path, pass these values to [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path)).
- The above, due to involving only a *single* comparison operation, was able to employ [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax); that is, `Where-Object DisplayName -match 'Teamviewer|Kaspersky|LogMeIn'` is the simplified form of the following, [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)-based form (`{ ... }`), in which the pipeline input object must be referred to via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_); you need this form for more complex conditionals:

  ```bash
  Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match 'Teamviewer|Kaspersky|LogMeIn' }
  ```
- That is, the `.DisplayName` property value of each pipeline input object is compared to a [regex (regular expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), `'Teamviewer|Kaspersky|LogMeIn'`, using the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator.

  - The input object at hand is only passed through (output) if the comparison yields `$true` (possibly by type coercion; here, `-match` directly returns `$true` or `$false`)
  - Notes re `-match`:

    - It looks for *substrings* by default, and the alternation construct (`|`) makes it look for *any* of the three strings; using additional regex constructs (such as `^` to match only at the *start* of the input string) would be possible in order to further constrain the matching logic.
    - It is case-*insensitive* by default, as PowerShell generally is; use the `-cmatch` variant for case-*sensitive* matching.

Comment: Thanks mklement0,
I was working around what you suggested and it did work (partially, probably because winver on those pc, even when they all are 10/11) and I notice that there are 2 registries to pull the info, but still working sometimes and some not, giving not result, even when I checked software (word) are there installed. Go figure. Thanks!!

So I couldn't get a bullet-proof command line for all installed.

Comment: @KuntaKinke, good point; there are _two_ registry location on 64-bit machines, one for 64-bit and another for 32-bit applications. I've updated the answer accordingly; you can additionally select the `PSPath` property so you can tell which location a given result comes from. If the command still fails to find entries, the implication is either that the applications in question where installed using a different mechanism, or the registry entries were manually removed.